# Confused as to why pygame is displaying a black screen

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code. I followed a tutorial, and spent a lot of time trying to bug fix it

What can I change to make pygame display what I have typed?

```
import pygame
import random
from random import randint
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,750)) 
background = pygame.image.load('cityscape python.jpg')


Bird = pygame.image.load('bird.png')
bird_x = 50
bird_y = 300
bird_y_change = 0

def display_bird(x,y):
  screen.blit(Bird, (x,y))


Obstacle_Width = 70
Obstacle_Height = random.randint(150,450)
Obstacle_Colour = (221, 253, 117)
Obstacle_X_Change = -4
obstacle_x = 500
bottom_obstacle_height = 0

def display_obstacle(height):
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, Obstacle_Colour, (obstacle_x, 0, Obstacle_Width, height))
  botton_obstacle_heiht = 635 - height - 158
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, Obstacle_Colour, (obstacle_x, 635, Obstacle_Width, -bottom_obstacle_height))


def collision_detection (obstacle_x, Obstacle_Height, bird_y, bottom_obstacle_height):
  if obstacle_x >= 50 and obstacle_x <= (50 + 64):
    if bird_y <= Obstacle_Height or bird_y >= (bottom_obstacle_height - 64):
      return True
  return False

score = 0
score_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

def score_display(score):
  display = score_font.render(f"score: {score}", True, (255,255,255))

Running = True

while Running:

  screen.fill((0,0,0))
 #line 50 displays the background image.
  screen.blit(background,(0,0))
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      Running = False
    change by -6.
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        bird_y_change = -6

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
      if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        bird_y_change = -3  


  bird_y += bird_y_change
 
  if bird_y <= 0:
    bird_y = 0
  if bird_y >= 571:
    bird_y = 571

obstacle_x += Obstacle_X_Change
if obstacle_x <= -10:
  obstacle_x = 500
  Obstacle_Height = random.randint(200,400)
display_obstacle(Obstacle_Height )



collision = collision_detection(obstacle_x, Obstacle_Height, bird_y, Obstacle_Height, + 150)

if collision:
  pygame.quit()


 .
display_bird(bird_x, bird_y)


score_display(score)

  

pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The while loop is blocking pygame from rendering anything. Can you link to the tutorial?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rO_UU_Uu8EQ&t=319s for the code.

Comment: Is your indentation correct here? For example, looking at `obstacle_x += Obstacle_X_Change`, your code doesn't match  - https://github.com/Anish-Malla/Flappy-birds-game-using-pygame/blob/master/Flappy_bird/main.py#L139-L140

Comment: Also, you have some line that says `change by -6.` which is not valid code, so the shown code here doesn't run as-is

Comment: @OneCricketeer the code is working perfectly fine, I checked replit (the python software that my school uses) and I don't really see a problem with the indentation. But then again I am very new to python so I don't really know.

Comment: It's not "working fine". Otherwise, you wouldnt create this post :) In the code that you pasted here, that line is not within the loop, and the loop does not stop. As the answer below says, nothing within your loop calls a function that does `pygame.draw`, so the loop just constantly fills the screen `screen.fill` and `screen.blit`, then acts of key-events, and repeats...

Comment: @OneCricketeer I fixed it, Thanks for your help. It means a lot!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a point in your while loop where it will update the game board, your pygame.display.update() is outside of the loop!

```
while Running:

  screen.fill((0,0,0))
 #line 50 displays the background image.
  screen.blit(background,(0,0))
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        Running = False
    #change by -6.
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        bird_y_change = -6

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
      if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        bird_y_change = -3  


  bird_y += bird_y_change
 
  if bird_y <= 0:
    bird_y = 0
  if bird_y >= 571:
    bird_y = 571
```